# Confusion about boolean recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

For this recursive method, I draw out a recursive trace to figure whether `recTest(a,0,4)` would return true or false.

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean recTest(int[] a, int i, int j){
        if(i>=j) return true;
        else if(a[i] > a[i+1]) return false;
        return recTest(a, i+1, j);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {3,6,8,7,9};
        System.out.println(Main.recTest(a,0,4));
        System.out.println(Main.recTest(a,1,4));
        System.out.println(Main.recTest(a,2,4));
        System.out.println(Main.recTest(a,3,4));
        System.out.println(Main.recTest(a,4,4));
    }

}
```

I got this (when I did it by hand):

```
recTest(a,0,4) calls recTest(a,1,4)
recTest(a,1,4) calls recTest(a,2,4)
recTest(a,2,4) calls recTest(a,3,4)
recTest(a,3,4) calls recTest(a,4,4)
recTest(a,4,4) returns true [base case]
```

Therefore, I thought that `recTest(a,0,4)` would similarly return true (since the "lowest" the recursion goes returns true). But it doesn't. Here's the output I received after drawing it out:

```
false
false
false
true
true
```

Would appreciate an explanation as to what exactly is happening here.

Comment: Question downvoted without explanation of why...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is off here:

```
recTest(a,2,4) calls recTest(a,3,4)
```

Since `a[2]` is greater than `a[3]`, `recTest()` returns `false` instead of calling itself again.

You can easily spot this by using a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What happens is:

```
recTest(a,0,4) calls recTest(a,1,4)
recTest(a,1,4) calls recTest(a,2,4)
recTest(a,2,4) returns false
```

as the else if statement `a[2] > a[3]` respectively `8 > 7` is fulfilled. That's why `recTest(a,0,4)` finally returns `false`.

Just for the sake of completeness:

```
recTest(a,3,4) calls recTest(a,4,4)
recTest(a,4,4) returns true
```

Comment: Damn, a millisecond too slow ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
recTest(a,0,4) in the end calls recTest(a,2,4)=>false as the condition is if(a[2]>a[3])=> 8>7 => false
recTest(a,1,4) in the end calls recTest(a,2,4)=>false 
recTest(a,2,4) if(a[2]>a[3])=> 8>7 => false
recTest(a,3,4) if(a[3]>a[4])=> 7>9(false) => recTest(a,4,4) i=j=> true
recTest(a,4,4) returns true [base case]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an if-else statement before the recursion, so I think your rationale behind it is not valid.
Put your code in an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ and see the value of the variables in each iteration, and you'll see it makes perfect sense.